# Ошибка: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead."

Tags: json, swift4

День добрый, у меня возникает ошибка "Expected to decode Dictionary < String, Any > but found an array instead." при попытке декодить json. По моей логике я вроде сделал все правильно, однако не могу понять в чем проблема и где я опростоволосился.

```
 URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: r) { (data, response, error) in
        do{
            guard let data = data else { return }
            let banners = try JSONDecoder().decode([Banner].self, from: data)
            print(banners)
        } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }.resume()

struct Banner: Decodable {
    var title: String
    var desc: String
    var image: String
}
```

JSONResponse:

```
[
  {
   "id": "b4a95512-8de2-4621-8956-3289e991fb0b",
   "image": "https://picsum.photos/500/324/"
  },
  {
   "id": "4e1c703d-4841-469b-be2e-8f15d6cbd0c3",
   "title": "Lays",
   "image": "https://picsum.photos/500/324/"
  },
  {
   "id": "4315705e-e6fc-4dfa-a52e-c9de2031ed53",
   "desc": "ФРУТОНЯНЯ Для детского питания с яблоком, для малышей от 0 до 3 лет",
   "image": "https://picsum.photos/500/324/"
  },
  {
   "id": "0b8e40ae-5e13-4bdd-905d-a13ffdd94b65",
   "title": "Бульмени",
   "desc": "ГОРЯЧАЯ ШТУЧКА Со сливочным маслом",
   "image": "https://picsum.photos/500/324/"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте такую структуру:

```
struct Banner: Codable {
    var id: String
    var title: String?
    var desc: String?
    var image: String?
}
```

Comment: Благодарю, ты лучший!